# Are these two measures actually the same?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This question recently occurred to me and I wasn't able to get to any conclusions yet, so I decided to ask for help. I think the question is well-posed but, please, let me know if something is wrong or missing.

Let us consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with its usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$ (generated by open sets) and $\mu$ a Borel measure on $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{n}})$. Let $\rho: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a given continuous function and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. I think there is no loss of generality in assuming $a > 0$ here. Since $\rho^{-1}(\{a\}) := \Omega_{a}$ is closed, it is Borel measurable. Consider it as a measure space itself, with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{\Omega_{a}}$ given by the restriction of $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$ to $\Omega_{a}$ and $\mu_{a}$ the Borel measure restricted to $(\Omega_{a},\mathcal{B}_{\Omega_{a}})$.

On the other hand, suppose $\delta > 0$ is fixed and consider an analogous set $\Omega_{[a,a+\delta]}$, which is a Borel set defined by:
$$\Omega_{[a,a+\delta]} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \rho(x) \in [a,a+\delta]\}.$$
Obviously, $\Omega_{a} \subset \Omega_{[a,a+\delta]}$. For each continuous and compactly supported function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$, define:
$$\ell(f) := \lim_{\delta \to 0}\frac{1}{\delta}\int_{\Omega_{[a,a+\delta]}}f(x)d\mu(x).$$
This is easily seen to be a positive linear functional, so by Riesz-Markov there exists a Borel measure $\nu_{a}$ on $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{n}})$ such that:
$$\ell(f) = \int f(x) d\nu_{a}(x).$$

I know that $\nu_{a}$ is supported on $\Omega_{a}$. So, my question is: is $\nu_{a} = \mu_{a}$? This seems to be true, as this is basically a "Dirac delta function" argument, but I wasn't able to prove it tho.

Comment: You said $\mu$ is a Borel measure, why is even $\ell$ well-defined in this case? If you're taking functions with compact support, you most likely want to a Radon measure instead.

Comment: @Jakobian I apologize, there was a typo in the definition of $\ell$. It must be normalized by $\delta^{-1}$.

Comment: @Jakobian and I also changed the notation of $\Omega_{a+\delta}$ as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexOrtiz yes, it was a typo!

Comment: I mean still, nothing in here indicates for why would $\ell$ be well-defined, the measure $\mu$ doesn't play in any way with compact functions here, it seems.

Comment: @Jakobian: To make a well-defined $\ell$, I think we can modify the definition of $\ell$ to take either $\limsup$ or $\liminf$, and use continuous compactly supported functions as our test functions to define $\ell$. Either way, this introduces two new operations, and we could declare the limit to exist when $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ agree. I don't know what properties these upper and lower limits have for something like a "fractal" measure, but for smooth hypersurfaces, they are well understood and fairly ubiquitous

Comment: @AlexOrtiz just noticed another typo: $\ell$ is supposed to be defined on continuous compactly supported functions, not just compactly supported as I wrote. Does this suffice to make $\ell$ well-defined?

Comment: @IamWill: I think regardless of the test class of functions, we need to define $\ell$ as something like a $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ to ensure the limit value of $\ell$ exists. It will be a theorem then that for "nice" $\rho$, $\limsup = \liminf$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz I was more worried about the limit being finite in the first place, so that we can consider $\ell$ as a linear functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, $\nu_a$ won't agree with $\mu_a$. Consider the Lebesgue measure $\mu$, and the function $\rho(x) = 1-|x|^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$, say. The level set $\{\rho = 0\}$ is the unit sphere, while $\{0\le \rho\le \delta\}$ is a thin shell. When you define $\ell(f)$ in the manner of your post (by differentiating the Lebesgue measure $\mu$), you get $\ell(f) = \int_{S^2}f\,d\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the surface measure of $S^2$. On the other hand, if we just restrict the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ to $\{\rho = 0\}$, we get the zero measure because the unit sphere is a set of $\mu$-measure $0$.